# Why 'beeware create android' doesn't work for me?

Tags: android, command, beeware

I wanted to create my app for android using beeware. When I tried 'beeware create android' command, I got this error:

```
usage: briefcase [-h] <command> [<platform>] [<format>] ...
briefcase: error: argument platform: invalid choice: 'android' (choose from 'iOS', 'linux', 'macOS', 'windows')
```

I don't understand because beeware should support android now. Do you have any idea what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: `briefcase --version` and check that it's 0.3.3

Comment: thanks! it was 0.3.0, so reinstalled it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

[Guy Incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8898840/guy-incognito) answered this in his comment:

briefcase --version and check that it's 0.3.3 – Guy Incognito  Dec 8, 2020 at 19:10
...

thanks! it was 0.3.0, so reinstalled it and it works now. – RedLips Dec 9, 2020 at 11:03